# Calculate Axis break positions programmatically where gap is larger than X number of ticks

Tags: algorithm, graph, highcharts, axis-labels

I have a dataset similar to the picture below with some values that make the smaller portions of graph harder to read. I have been asked to put in an axis breaks when there is any continuous data sections longer than X number of ticks. Right now the breaks are calculated and put into the graph manually which doesn't work as the data changes in real time. This is being charted in highcharts although this is more a language and tool agnostic question.

```
breaks: [{
      from: 245,
      to: 505,
      breakSize: 3
    }, {
      from: 145,
      to: 215,
      breakSize: 3
    }, {
      from: 48,
      to: 59,
      breakSize: 3
    }],
```

[image: chart data with breaks]

Comment: Model each row of the graph as a series of events. For example the bottom row has events at 0, 88, 101, 140, 225, and 516. Put all of the events from all of the rows into a single array, and sort the array. Then scan the array to find gaps where the difference between two events is more than the minimum gap size.

Comment: You're welcome, but be aware that "aesthetically pleasing" is a very hard concept for a computer to understand. So that's just the beginning of your journey. Good luck!

Comment: you're so right, i already had to expand on finding these axis break locations and add some offset so they were not right in the middle of the number labels